# Cart always display free shipping

Tags: cart, magento-1, shipping, shipping-methods, free-shipping

In the cart I want to display in the totals block, always a free shipping line.
We ship our products always for free, so is there a way to display between the subtotal.phtml and tax.phtml always the shipping.phtml?

Currently this is only displayed when the fields of the checkout are filed.

Comment: Please check Shopping cart rules ....Magento shopping is  provide to setting to free.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to add it between you need to update the accordning layout file, which loads the corresponding phtml files and block elements and put them together, probably `checkout.xml` and the `checkout_cart_index` node. The problem is, the totals usually getting rendered from

```
app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/cart/totals.phtml
```

In here we got

```
<?php echo $this->renderTotals(); ?>
```

if you want to get between the total lines you need to adjust the renderer.